# Prevent users changing password in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, password

How can I prevent a user to change its password in FreeBSD. In Linux i can do this by using `chage -m 99999 <username>` where `chage` is found in `shadow-utils`

Reason for this is I created one shell account that is shared among 10 users and I don't want any of them to change its password.

Comment: Remove the suid bit from utilities such as `chpass` and `passwd`.

Comment: The sane solution is to not have a shared account, or if you must have a shared account, use SSH keys in a root-owned `~/.ssh`.

Comment: What is result please of `ls -l $(type -p passwd)`

Comment: Can you use groups, and shared home directory (and a `umask` of `rwxrwx---` is that `007` )

Answer (score -2):

As FreeBSD dos not implement a method to set the minimum time between passwd changes, there is no way to prevent users from changing the passwd on FreeBSD.

Comment: There are other ways to prevent users from changing the passwords than setting a minimum time between password changes.

Comment: Well, you don't seem to know another way, as you did not mention such a method.